# Pyspark Window Function

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to calculate the row_number on a data-set based on certain column but i am getting the below error

```html
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rowNumber'
```

I am using the below script to get the row number based on MID and ClaimID. Ay thoughts why this is coming up?

```html
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

def Codes(pharmacyCodes):

   df_data=pharmacyCodes

   
   (df_data
    .select("MID","claimid",
    F.rowNumber()
    .over(Window
               .partitionBy("MID")
               .orderBy("MID")
              )
         .alias("rowNum")

    )
    .show()
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `row_number` rather than `rowNumber`. The mixture of camel case and snake case with Pyspark can get confusing.

Comment: Thanks, i modified the code and it is working fine now.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).